# Is there a polynomial algorithm to find the max weighted perfect matching in a general graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I see that [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) can be used to solve the unweighted version of this problem, and I know that this problem can also be reduced to an LP problem (but with exponential numbers of constraints). Is there a way to solve it in polynomial time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Blossom algorithm for computing maximum unweighted general matchings can be used in a primal-dual algorithm for maximum weighted general matchings (this is a general technique; the Hungarian algorithm is the bipartite equivalent). There's an implementation called Blossom V due to Vladimir Kolmogorov.